# How to reuse shaders decompiled from disunity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, direct3d

I'm doing research on programmatically recreating golden cards from Hearthstone. I extracted some of the shaders Blizzard used to draw those cards using a tool called `disunity`, but it's in assembly, and there're some parts in random string, probably a type error.

Is there a way to use those shaders?

Here's a sample of a sub program:

```
SubProgram "d3d11 " {
Bind "vertex" Vertex
Bind "color" Color
Bind "texcoord" TexCoord0
Bind "texcoord1" TexCoord1
ConstBuffer "$Globals" 160
Vector 16 [_LightColor0]
Float 48 [_ScrollX1]
Float 52 [_ScrollY1]
Float 56 [_Scale1]
Float 88 [_ScrollX2]
Float 92 [_ScrollY2]
Float 96 [_Scale2]
Float 132 [_LightingBlend]
Vector 144 [_MainTex_ST]
ConstBuffer "UnityPerCamera" 128
Vector 0 [_Time]
ConstBuffer "UnityPerDraw" 336
Matrix 0 [glstate_matrix_mvp]
ConstBuffer "UnityPerFrame" 208
Vector 64 [glstate_lightmodel_ambient]
BindCB  "$Globals" 0
BindCB  "UnityPerCamera" 1
BindCB  "UnityPerDraw" 2
BindCB  "UnityPerFrame" 3
"vs_4_0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"
}
```

This is supposed to be part of a shader that renders texuture with "scrolling light distortion" effect

Comment: Unity tag has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine on stack overflow. Please don't use it with this kind of question.

Comment: It looks like a bug in disunity, and it probably [should be reported as issue on it's github page][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781448/how-to-reuse-shaders-decompiled-from-disunity

Comment: That string looks like a weird textual representation of the DXBC binary that is the shader that gets passed to the driver. I'm guessing that because most of the characters are 'a' which corresponds to a majority of DXBC bytes being 0. You'll need to convert it to actual binary and then disassemble it to get back to the actual shader. fxc.exe from the Windows SDK can disassemble binary shaders.